# How can I Serialize my class in json body?

Tags: c#, string, variables

i have this code string, i need serialize my class X, y try use concat with "+ +" but , dont work .. i use c# and nugget RestClient, and this forn not the optimum ty,

```
var body = @"{
" + "\n" +
        @"    ""CompanyDB"":""VARIABLE "",
" + "\n" +
        @"    ""UserName"":""VARIABLE "",
" + "\n" +
        @"    ""Password"":""VARIABLE ""
" + "\n" +
        @"}";
```

Comment: i use replace but, i want optimizate

Comment: What do you mean by `BUT DONT WORK`? What issue you are facing? What is `VARIABLE` here? can you share the code which you tried?

Comment: As an aside, I'd strongly encourage you to use a JSON library to create or parse JSON - this is just asking for problems if someone has a username including a backslash for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest building JSON using a JSON serializer, as it's much less error-prone.

Using JSON.NET:

```cs
var body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {
    CompanyDB = "abc",
    UserName = "def",
    Password = "ghi"
});
```

If you need to have the response formatted with newlines for some reason, you can pass `Formatting.Indented` to `SerializeObject` as the second argument.

[Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/v1SQJh)

Using System.Text.Json:

```cs
var body = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new {
    CompanyDB = "abc",
    UserName = "def",
    Password = "ghi"
});
```

If you need to have the response formatted with newlines for some reason, you can pass `new JsonSerializerOptions() { WriteIndented = true }` to `Serialize` as the second argument.

[Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rWNjTr)

Comment: IMHO this is less error prone as well, if dealing with json, one of these two options are best. You're dealing with a restclient that takes json, don't hack a way by creating glued together strings.

Answer (score 2):

It's as simple as this:

```
    var VARIABLE = "Hello";
    var body = @"{
" + "\n" +
        $@"    ""CompanyDB"":""{VARIABLE} "",
" + "\n" +
        $@"    ""UserName"":""{VARIABLE} "",
" + "\n" +
        $@"    ""Password"":""{VARIABLE} ""
" + "\n" +
        @"}";
```

---

It can even be simpler:

```
    var body = $@"{{

    ""CompanyDB"":""{VARIABLE} "",

    ""UserName"":""{VARIABLE} "",

    ""Password"":""{VARIABLE} ""

}}";
```

Comment: i know this can be ez, but i complicated jaajj  , ty so much @Enigmativity

Comment: @Ignacio - The JSON answer is better than mine.